# Symmetric 1D array Python

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy

So I have

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
```

I want to check if the array is symmetric. So the output would be `False`

Another example would be

```
arr = [1,2,3,3,2,1]
out = fun(arr)
out = True
```

I have been trying by like

```
def checksymm(a):
    flag = 0

    for i in range(0,len(a)/2):
        if np.abs(a[i]) == np.abs(a[-i]):
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

What can I be doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Why would you use `np.abs` here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Corresponding of `a[i]` should be `a[-1-i]`, not `a[-i]`.

Besides, why not just reverse the list and compare each elements:

```
def isSymmetric(arr):
    return (arr == arr[::-1]).all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most efficient way would be to restrict the comparison to each half of the array:

```
n = len(arr) // 2
result = np.all(arr[:n] == arr[-1:-n - 1:-1])
```

With absolute values:

```
result = (np.abs(arr[:n]) == np.abs(arr[-1:-n - 1:-1])).all()
```

Both formulations should work directly with either lists or arrays.

Answer (score 0):

When you compare, pay attention to the index, 0 with -1, 1 with -2 etc (not 1 with -1), so it should be `i` and `-i-1` . Also instead of returning `True` after finding one equality , you should return after all of them are equal ...

```
arr = [1,2,3,3,2,1]

def checksymm(a):

    for i in range(0,len(a)//2):
        if a[i] != a[-i-1]: # or  np.abs(a[i]) != np.abs(a[-i-1]) as in the original code
            return False
    return True

    
out = checksymm(arr)
print(out)
```

`>>> True`

And :

```
arr = [1,2,3,3,5,1]
out = checksymm(arr)
print(out)
```

`>>> False`

Edit :  I tried to find the problem with your code and fix it, but I would recommand the answer of @songziming it's better.